# set transparent navigation bar in split views detailview

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uikit, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a UISplitViewController with master & detail. Both embedded into a UINavigationController.

When push to detail i'm setting this to improve usability across devices.

```
        let controller = (segue.destination as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! ProjectViewController
        controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem
        controller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
```

I want the navigationBar to be transparent in the detailView. Which works great on iPad with:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar
```

but not on iPhone.

Thank you so much for any help!

Comment: the splitViewController has `preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayMode.allVisible`

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution:

```
self.parent?.navigationController?.navigationBar
```

Comment: I tried to set .barStyle with this, but it works only on the first time? after I "back" to the master, and then go to the details again, the .barStyle setting doesn't take effect.

Comment: Maybe you did add that line into viewDidLoad? Try to add it into viewWillAppear instead

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.clear`

Comment: it's not about how to make a navigationBar transparent but about how to access the navigationBar in this situation.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question

Comment: So Can't you get and store your navigationcontroller from segue.destination as? UINavigationController and then try to change the bartinticolor??

Comment: yip this was the problem. But I solved it by my self. you can get the navigationBar on iPhone from the detailView like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45378618/6638543

Comment: Glad you found:)